# How to get a td value using SimpleHTMLDOM?

Tags: php, html, curl, simple-html-dom

I have the following table which I'm trying to scrape with SimpleHtmlDom.

How would I reference/access the date value of "application received" and put it in to a variable. I've tried using the plain text approach, but this produces all the text in all of the td's.

```
<table id="simpleDetailsTable" summary="Case Details">

                        <tbody><tr>
                            <th scope="row" width="40%">
                                Reference
                            </th>
                            <td>
                             LA01/2018/0235/F

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" width="40%">
                                Application Received
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                Fri 23 Feb 2018
                               <td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" width="40%">
                                Address
                            </th>
                            <td>
                       206 Straid Road Bushmills.

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" width="40%">
                                Proposal
                            </th>
                            <td>
                          Alterations to existing car showroom.

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" width="40%">
                                Status
                            </th>
                            <td>

                            <span class="caseDetailsStatus">Application Received</span>

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" width="40%">
                                Authority Decision
                            </th>
                            <td>
                        Not Available

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" width="40%">
                                Authority Decision Date
                            </th>
                            <td>
                              Not Available

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" width="40%">
                                PAC Decision
                            </th>
                            <td>
                           Not Available

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" width="40%">
                                PAC Decision Date
                            </th>
                            <td>
                              Not Available

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
```

Using the following code I'm able to echo out each listing.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$item);
                 $output = curl_exec($ch);
                 $html = str_get_html($output);
                 $table = $html->find('table',0);
                 $rowdata = array();
                 foreach($table->find('tr') as $row){
                  foreach($row->find('td') as $cell){
                        $listing = $cell->plaintext;

                     echo $listing,'<br>';
                        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($listing);echo'<pre/>';
                        }
                     }
```

which produces the following result;

LA01/2018/0254/O
Tue 27 Feb 2018
39 Lyttlesdale Garvagh.
Proposed new dwelling and proposed new paired access to include demolition of existing garage.
Application Received
Not Available
Not Available
Not Available
Not Available

LA10/2018/0265/F
Tue 27 Feb 2018
45 Glen Road Killyculla Tempo BT94 3JU
Replacement dwelling-amended position,house type (split level) and domestic garage from previous approval LA10/2017/0529/RM for same
Application Received
Not Available
Not Available
Not Available
Not Available

Can anyone put me right on what it is I should be doing?

Comment: Seems like it's working. What's your question?

Comment: My effort gets me the return as shown, however, what I'm struggling with  is how to lets say get just the address line back from each listing.I have tried the td children approach, but to no avail.

Comment: Looks like you need to switch to a parser that supports `:contains`